# CSS background color wont work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my background color of #about a certain color, but when I do it doesn't work. The other code, like the height works but not the background.

CSS:

```
#menu-toggle {
padding: 0px;
background-color: transparent;
color: #ff2626;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 50px;
border-color: transparent;
position: fixed;
}

.header-img {
background-image: url(../img/crossfitheader.jpg);
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
height: 100vh;
}

.icon-menu:before {
content: "\e9bd";
}

.container #about  {
height: 100vh;
width:100%:
background-color: #575432 !important;
}

.icon-cross:before {
content: "\ea0f";
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="about">
    hiuhjjkn
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

Answer (score 2):

Because having a colon after `width:100%:` stops it.

Replace it with semicolon:

```
width:100%;
```

Otherwise it is treated as if you continue to specify your width.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `:` with a `;` on your width property like this:

```
width:100%;
```

Here is a jsfiddle of your codes with the `colon` replaced with a `semi-colon`: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/32/

Comment: haha You have no idea how many times small s#!t like this happens to me too lol

Comment: If the explanation as well as the jsfiddle example on my answer helped you in solving your problem, then do mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`width:100%:` <<< you have a colon and not a semi-colon

Answer (score 0):

change it to this

```
.container #about  {
height: 100vh;
width:100%: <---- instead of : put ;
background-color: #575432 !important;
}
```

Comment: You are too late. Three identical answers were already provided.